# SQL query: joins+condition+order

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables:
user(use_id, use_role),
message(mes_id, from_use_id[fk->user.use_id], mes_create_at),
message_user(mes_use_id, mes_id[fk->message.mes_id], to_use_id[fk->user.use_id])

User can be use_role=1(student) or use_role=2(teacher).
I have to get all Users that are use_type=1(student) sorted by last contact with teacher. No matter if student write to teacher or teacher write to student.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show us your current progress on your problem so we can point you in the right direction! How are you to learn if you just copy/pasta? :D

Comment: Stackoverflow <> Homeworkoverflow

Comment: Hi :)  I spent all day on it but the best what i wrote was: select * from (SELECT  `u` . * ,  `m` . * ,  `mu` . * 
FROM  `user` AS  `u` 
INNER JOIN  `message` AS  `m` ON u.use_id = m.from_use_id
INNER JOIN  `message_user` AS  `mu` ON u.use_id = mu.to_use_id
WHERE u.use_role =1
ORDER BY m.mes_create_at) as `us` group by `us`.`use_id` and the response is : "#1060 - Duplicate column name 'mes_id'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you use ms sql:

```
select *
from
(
    select student.use_id, Message.mes_create_at, Message.from_use_id, Message_User.to_use_id
    from User student
    join Message on Message.use_id = student.use_id and student.use_role = 1
    join Message_User on Message_User.mes_id = Message.mes_id
    where Message_User.to_use_id in (select use_id from User where use_role = 2)

    union

    select Message_User.to_use_id, Message.mes_create_at, Message.from_use_id, Message_User.to_use_id
    from User teacher
    join Message on Message.use_id = teacher.use_id and teacher.use_role = 2
    join Message_User on Message_User.mes_id = Message.mes_id
    where Message_User.to_use_id in (select use_id from User where use_role = 1)
) as temp
order by mes_create_at desc
```

Comment: Thanks! I am very grateful to you. I just had to modify your answer a little and add one simple thing and now it works :D  modification: Message.use_id -> Message.from_use_id. Additional code:  `SELECT * 
FROM (your answer ) AS temp1
GROUP BY  temp1.use_id`

Comment: I am glad you can make use of it.